# Button with Image with same height as UIElement in previous Grid.Column

Tags: c#, wpf

I am pretty new to WPF so please bear with me.
I would like to show combobox with button next to it. Button will contain image. Image dimensions are 64x64. I would like to have combobox height as master height for whole Grid row. I need to force button with image to be as height as combobox. I do not want to specify any hardcoded values (I will use DevExpress themes later).

I suppose I have working solution (at least for runtime) but I would like to check with someone more experienced. Solution is based on buttons height binding to combobox ActualHeight. This works in runtime pretty well. But in design time button size is much bigger (it is showing image in its original dimensions).

Is my solution recommended one? How to solve design time issue? It is driving me crazy that I see in design time something I do not see in runtime.

I am using VS 2015 Community edition

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Issue.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Issue"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Title="Window1">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Cbx"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=Cbx, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Image Source="Play.png"/>
    </Button>
    <Label Content="Hello" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Content="Big Hello" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="15"/>
</Grid>
```

Image - designtime/runtime

[image: Design time / run time]

Thanks,

Comment: Bind the height of your image to the ActualHeight property of the combo box. Something like height={Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=ActualHeight}

Comment: Binding image height to ActualHeight has actually worse result than binding Button's height. Image is much much bigger in design time and even in runtime

Comment: Binding to the ActualHeight of the Combobox ist totally correct. Problem is that the VS designer is not executing runtime code. In your special example with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` I can't think of a solution how to solve this.

Comment: Yes sorry, you're right to try setting this on the button not the image. If design time still an issue, I'm not sure. You can try manipulating the row height setting to auto or putting the button or image in a viewbox - if either work, it's still unnecessary markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be solved by Canvas. Canvas will not change its size based on content so it can contain content bigger than canvas and still canvas will not change height/width of row/column of grid where canvas is laid. Thus binding of button with image height works like a miracle in run-time and even in design time.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Cbx"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=Cbx, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Button Height="{Binding ElementName=Cbx, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <Image Source="Play.png"/>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
    <Label Content="Hello" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Content="Big Hello" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="15"/>
</Grid>
```